# How to Parse and Combine More than 1 RSS Feed into One Feed using Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, rss, swift

Im trying to implement a Feature into My iOS 7/8 Project using Swift that Parses and Combines more than 1 Feed into one feed and displaying it into a UITableView. The Array of RSS Links will come from a CoreData Entity that contains all the info about the RSS Feeds like Name of the Feed, Website URL, Description and ofcause RSS URL. But I Dont know how to parse each RSS URL and Combine them into an Array. I Do know that it may involve a for loop for the Parse Ive tried to find tutorials and how to do this but with no success There where only PHP type Tutorials but no cocoa tutorials. Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Thank You :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can take help from below tutorials if you need only parsing infomration

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/rss-reader-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

they are in `objective-c`.You can take help from it.

Comment: Wasn't me who down voted I gave your comment a Tick and someone Down Vote the Whole Question too